# Why is Remove-NcSnapmirror removing SnapMirror relationship on BOTH source and destination? (NETAPP ONTAP PowerShell Toolkit)

Tags: powershell, ssh, storage, netapp, ontap

**TLDR:** SSH command *snapmirror delete* works fine, PowerShell command *Remove-NcSnapmirror* misbehaves for SnapMirror relationship removal.

**PowerShell cmdlet:** The
*Remove-NcSnapMirror*
cmdlet is supposed to delete the SnapMirror relationship only on the destination cluster.

But for some reason, using this command removes the relationship on the source as well because of which SnapMirror resync cannot be used.

**SSH cmd:** The *snapmirror delete* command works perfectly fine, which deletes the SnapMirror relationship ONLY on the destination cluster. After this step, I am able to run *snapmirror resync* to resync the SnapMirror relationship.

Comment: What is `Remove-NcSnapmirror`? Do you have a link to its module documentation or where you downloaded it?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It is available with the NETAPP ONTAP PowerShell Toolkit. Unfortunately, you won’t find much documentation on it online.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going for *Invoke-NcSsh* as atleast it can call the SSH commands in a PowerShell script so it’s fine.

It’s not the PowerShell way, but it is a way.